# Do Laplace-Beltrami eigenfunctions vary continuously with the metric?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory, laplacian, eigenfunctions

I'm interested in Laplace Beltrami operators $$-\Delta_g:\ \   D(-\Delta_g) \longrightarrow L^2\left(M,\sqrt{|g|}dx\right)$$
on a smooth compact Riemannian Manifold (M,g). Let us fix a unique metric $g$ on $M$. 
For any other smooth metric $\widetilde g$ on $M$, we can identify the square integrable functions with respect to its associated volume form with our original $L^2$ above, via the unitary map
$U:f\longmapsto \sqrt{|g|/|\widetilde g|}f.$
Under this unitary identification the Laplace-Beltrami operators corresponding to the various smooth metrics on $M$ yield a family of operators on a common domain of definition.
It has been [proved](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/tohoku-mathematical-journal/volume-35/issue-2/Generic-properties-of-the-eigenvalue-of-the-Laplacian-for-compact/10.2748/tmj/1178229047.full) that the eigenvalues of this family depend continuously on the metrics.

Is this true for the eigenfunctions (or eigenprojections) as well?

I know that if I consider an analytic one parameter family of metrics the result holds essentially by Kato's perturbation theory.
But I am ultimately interested in proving that a certain composition of maps from functions on the manifold to $\mathbb R$  is robust to arbitrary, small (in the $C^\infty$-topology) changes in the metric and one of the maps in the composition is an operator of the form $f(-\Delta_g)$.

This is my first question here, so if I'm transgressing against any etiquette rules, please do let me know. :)

Comment: In your second to last paragraph, is the function $f$ continuous? If so, then showing (say strong) continuity of the map $g\mapsto f(-\Delta_g)$ may be easier than showing continuity of the eigenprojections.

Comment: Things can go wrong when the eigenvalues have multiplicity $>1$.